# Convert z-scores to percentile rank

Tags: z-statistic

Does anyone know the formula to convert a z-score to a percentile rank instead of using the z-score table? I searched the website, but did not find the formula.

thank you

Comment: There are approximation formulas of various kinds for computing the cdf or survivor function of a standard normal; which might be suitable depends on the circumstances. What are you using it for - e.g. are you writing code?

Comment: The formula is given by the Normal cumulative density function, defined as $\int_{-\infty}^z \exp(-x^2/2)dx /\sqrt{2\pi}.$ There are many ways to compute this as exactly as one would like: conceptually it's no different, say, than the definition of the logarithm as $\log(z)=\int_1^z dx/x.$ This is why @Glen_b seeks more information concerning your objectives, which you can provide by editing this question.

Answer (score 3):

Like in the comments, there's a known function that describes the relationship. The reason you use a table is that the function is ugly. It can be calculated very easily by a computer but not at all by hand. So before everyone had R in front of them it was the best way to "calculate" a value from $F(x)$ when you needed one -- just look it up in the table.

If you want to know more about the theory, I'd refer you to any intro probability textbook... which imo you should already be using if you're going to be using z-scores.

This is done in R with function `pnorm`. This is the standard set of functions for a distribution in R:

- `r`:  input $N$, get $N$ random values
- `p`:  input $X$, get $F(X)$
- `d`:  input $X$, get $f(x)$
- `q`:  input $p$, get $F^{-1}(p)$

Try it out:

```
dt(1.65,df=30)
df(2,df1=2,df2=30)
df(-2,df1=2,df2=30) # F distribution is for positive random variables
qnorm(0.95)
pnorm(1.65)
dnorm(1.65)
runif(15)
```

And if you want to know more about how exactly the computer calculates $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}dt$ when you give it an $x$, you'll be wanting to know about [numerical integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, but I went ahead and created a hash table from the z-scores & I'll use that instead, unless someone knows what Java class I could find a function to do this in. I thought if I had the formula I could use that , but I don't think I would be able to figure out how to use it without a big investment in time.

Comment: @user3787792 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011943/java-normal-distribution